# reading CSV file specific column and row with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a basic script that reads a csv file and I pull the specific column I want. The only challenge I have now is how to grab the specific row in that column.

Below is the code I have now.

```
import csv
with open('CopyofNetflowExporters-v1.5-csv.csv') as csvfile:
csvitem=csv.reader(csvfile)
#csvitem = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in csvitem:
    print(row[11])
```

Comment: And ? How are we supposed to know which row you want exactly ?

Comment: you should look into pandas, it's very helpful for stuff like this https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get in `csvitem` is a list of lists, where the first index is a row number, and the second index is a column number

You are not grabbing a column in your example. You are printing nth element of each row.
To have column as an indexable object you need either to append to a list instead of prinitng in your example (that will only give you that one column as a list) or you can transpose the entire contents of the file, which is more interesting and which is shown below

```
transposed_csv = list(zip(*csvitem))
# now you have a list of columns, while each column is a tuple of strings
print(transposed_csv[2])
```

Comment: This was it and thank you very much! So I added the column I wanted and row with the addition of this extra snippet to it.

Comment: import csv
with open('CopyofNetflowExporters-v1.5-csv.csv') as csvfile:
    csvitem=csv.reader(csvfile)
    transposed_csv = list(zip(*csvitem))
    print(transposed_csv[11][3])

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
import csv
with open('CopyofNetflowExporters-v1.5-csv.csv') as csvfile:
     csvitem=list(csv.reader(csvfile))
     print(csvitem[11])
```